# Excel VBA close current workbook Error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I have some VBA code in an Excel workbook.
I have a cell which I would like to use to close the workbook without saving (instead of using the usual (X) close button on the top right corner of excel.

If I close the workbook using the (X) button, it works great the following code.
However if I press the "CLOSE" button cell which is on the worksheet, it gives a 1004 error.

Can anyone help?

ON WORKSHEET WHERE BUTTON IS

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column) = "CLOSE" Then

    CloseNoSave
End If

End Sub
```

IN THISWORKBOOK

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    CloseNoSave

End Sub
```

IN MODULE

```
Sub CloseNoSave()

    ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use a single piece of code on your `Selection` Event

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If ActiveCell.Value = "CLOSE" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
        ThisWorkbook.Close
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks brettdj ! That did it !
I also added ThisWorkbook.Saved = True to Workbook_BeforeClose and I can now close workbook without saving either pressing in X or the "close" button on the sheet !

Comment: Ok, seems like I still have the same problem.
In order to make the excel 2007 as "neat" as possible, I have added the following code to windowActivate/windowDeactivate.

If ribbon is hidden, and press either X or CLOSE button, it causes the error 1004 to occur again.

Any ideas how to solve ?

Private Sub Workbook_WindowActivate(ByVal Wn As Window)

    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"", false)"

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_WindowDeactivate(ByVal Wn As Window)

    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"", true)"

End Sub